# MySQL #1064 error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

while i have googled for solutions for quite a time i still couldn't find where this error is nested.

I could create a fine table that didn't generate any problems with this

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jcom_11645246_silowniainz_karta`.`Cennik` ( 
  `Klub_idKlubu` INT NOT NULL , 
  `Kategoria` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
  `Nazwa` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
  `Koszt` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL , 
  `Id` INT NOT NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`Klub_idKlubu`, `Id`) , 
  INDEX `fk_Cennik_Klub` (`Klub_idKlubu` ASC) , 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Cennik_Klub` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`Klub_idKlubu` ) 
    REFERENCES `jcom_11645246_silowniainz_karta`.`Klub` (`idKlubu` ) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) 
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Problematic create table looks like this

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jcom_11645246_silowniainz_karta`.`Ogloszenie` ( 
  `idOgloszenia`  NOT NULL , 
  `Klub_idKlubu` INT NOT NULL , 
  `TytulOgloszenia` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL , 
  `TrescOgloszenia` VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`Klub_idKlubu`, `idOgloszenia`) , 
  INDEX `fk_Ogloszenia_Klub` (`Klub_idKlubu` ASC) , 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ogloszenia_Klub` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`Klub_idKlubu` ) 
    REFERENCES `jcom_11645246_silowniainz_karta`.`Klub` (`idKlubu` ) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) 
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

And error looks like this

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL , 
  `Klub_idKlubu` INT NOT NULL , 
  `TytulOgloszenia` VARCHAR(40) N' at line 2
```

I can't see what is so different between table1 and table2 structure that could have caused this error. I've looked for " ' ", too many " , " or lack of ";". Can I get some help on this?

Comment: MyISAM doesn't have `FOREIGN KEY`s as far as I'm aware. Though that's not the cause of your syntax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the type here:

```
`idOgloszenia`  NOT NULL ,
```

Just insert a type like `INT` and it will work.

```
`idOgloszenia` INT NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: Jeez, I'm blind, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you where to look, which is here:

> ```
>  `idOgloszenia`  NOT NULL
> ```

You forgot to write the type of the field, so `NOT NULL` is unexpected at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Your query lacks an `INT` on line 2 :

```
`idOgloszenia` INT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm brain afk :D